# When does instantiation happens when you pass an object as an argument

Tags: swift, oop

Really basic question. I'm currently trying to code in a more Object Oriented way but there is something that I don't fully understand. I believe this applies to multiple programming languages not only `Swift` because I have seen this in some PHP code too.

I was under the impression that in order for you to access methods in a class you would need to create an instance but I'm not sure how this happens when you pass objects as parameters.

In the code below the `moveDog(move:Animal)` method gets an `Animal` object as a parameter, what I don't know understand is how can you access methods form the `Animal` object without instantiating the class first (`print(move.run())`)?

Does instantiation happens when declaring local parameters `moveDog(move:Animal)`? Can we say that it is the same as if we would do `let move = Animal()`?

```
class Animal{
    func run(){
        print("Running...")
    }
}

class Dog{
    func moveDog(move:Animal){
        //how can the run method be called without
        //having to instantiate Animal?
        print(move.run())
    }
}

let dog = Animal()

let buddy = Dog()

buddy.moveDog(dog)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialisation happens when you actually create it, e.g. `let dog = Animal()` or `let buddy = Dog()`.

A quick note, you can make this code better by using the same `run()` function by using inheritance like so:

```
class Animal{

    func run(){
        print("Running...")
    }
}


class Dog: Animal{

    override func run() {
        super.run() 
    }
}


let dog = Animal() //You don't need to instantiate this to use the Dog class

let buddy = Dog()

buddy.run()
```

In swift parameters are normally passed by reference (except structs) rather than being copied. So there's no initialisation for passing parameters.

Comment: So what is exactly happening here `print(move.run()`, how is the local variable `move` knows about methods inside `Animal`? it just has visibility to what `Animal` contains but no instance has been created?   **FYI - I'm learning about the `SOLID` principles, that is why I didn't use inheritance.**

Comment: If you're learning the `SOLID` principals you should be using inheritance. `Open/closed principle - software entities should be open for extension, but closed for modification` e.g extend the class using inheritance rather than changing it. You can see that it extends `Animal` by looking at the class. `class Dog: Animal`

Comment: Well, I'm not showing all of the code, I'm actually using a `protocol` in my code to conform to the `open close principle` (code to an interface not to a class). I'm just confused about the piece of code I pointed out. Thank you though.

Comment: Could you touch a little bit on what is happening here `print(move.run())`, how is the local variable `move` knows about methods inside `Animal`?  If no instance has been created how it knows.

Comment: Yeah sure. Because `Dog` inherits from `Animal` it can use it's public functions and extend them if needed. The user of `super.run()` is calling the `run()` function in `Animal`

Comment: I know about inheritance. I want to know about my original code `print(move.run())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98826/discussion-between-swinny89-and-fs-tigre).